# Is it possible to integrate Trac with VisualSVN Server 3?

Tags: trac, visualsvn-server

In older versions of the VisualSVN server, it was possible to integrate the Trac bugtracking system using a plugin found here: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/trac/

Unfortunately, now this page just says:

> The Trac plug-in for VisualSVN Server is not available anymore.
>
> Note that VisualSVN Server 3.2 brings fully revamped web browser for Subversion repositories. The new web browser is powered by HTML5 and ensures easy integration with third-party issue trackers.

But there is no hint on how this "easy integration" might work.

Is it still possible to integrate Trac with VisualVNC? If yes, how?